# Restrict movement on reaching map border or any objects

Tags: c#, xna

I'm totally new in game-dev and would like to know the best practice about above question.

Let me explain more.

I want to create 2D game with top-down view and with free movement (without snapping to the grid) just like any Zelda game on GameBoy.

How should I store map bounds? Is there a way to do this automatically? For example I have a texture with background and texture with foreground where black color should appear transparent and should allow to move in space of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's called 'collision detection' and there's litterally tons of information on the web on that.

Comment: Thanks ) I will search about it. I think your answer suffices for the first time )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For easy 2D collision detection, you'll probably implement bounding boxes.

Basically you will create a rectangle that represents every Game Object. The coordinates and size of the rectangle will be the same as the Texture2D (it is common to make this a property on the given class). Every time you update the position of your Texture, you update the position of your bounding box.

Now to check for collision, just loop through your game objects and see if any of the bounding boxes intersect.

Once you get the idea, you'll see that its very easy to implement. XNA also provides some math helpers to abstract the math (though its simple addition and subtraction).

Try this link for a more in depth explanation with code examples: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180069-xna-2d-bounding-box-collision-detection/